# how to animate google map view when change lat and lng?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-api-3, dart

I added google map inside column.

my inspector like this:

Scaffold
 - stack
  - singlechildscrollview
   - form
    - container
     - padding
      - column
       - sizedbox
        - googlemap

```
                     SizedBox(
                          width: width,
                          height:height * .4,
                          child: GoogleMap(
                            gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
                              Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                                      () => EagerGestureRecognizer())].toSet(),
                            mapType: MapType.normal,
                            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                                target: LatLng(lat, lng),
                                zoom: 15),
                            onCameraMove: (_)=>CameraPosition(
                                target: LatLng(lat, lng),
                                zoom: 15),
                            markers: Set<Marker>.of(<Marker>[
                          Marker(
                          markerId: MarkerId('id'),
                        position: LatLng(lat, lng),
                        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
                          ),
                        ]),
                        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                              setState(() {
                                controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
                                  LatLng(lat, lng),
                                ));
                              });
                            },
                          )),
```

Google map search

```
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _handlePressButton,
                child: Text("Search places"),
              ),

  Future<void> _handlePressButton() async {
    Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
      context: context,
      apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
      mode: Mode.overlay,
    );
    displayPrediction(p);
  }

  Future<void> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
          await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);
      setState(() {
        lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
        lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;
      });
    }
  }
```

**After change lat and LNG map is not animated but the marker changed.. how to animate google map view?**

Answer (score 0):

this is how you would go about it

```
 final GoogleMapController controller = await mapController;

    mapCcontroller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        bearing: 0,
        target: LatLng(lat, lon),
        zoom: 16.0,
      ),
));
```